# Selecting just a small set of values for a plot

Tags: r, plot, boxplot, aesthetics

I have table from which I get 5 box plots, it has only two columns with 15 values each. The plots are grouped by a variable "X" (from 1-5, each one repeated 3 times), how do I plot only one of those box plots?

Comment: You can subset your data before plotting. E.g., `ggplot(subset(your_data, X == 1), ....)`. If you need more help than that, please post a sample of your data.

Comment: I'd also add that 3 points isn't really enough for a good boxplot... with only 3 points I would probably just plot the points.